# WP Rest API in Android studio does not show Images

Tags: rest-api, json, android

I am developing WP API. I show you the screen of the problem:
https://ibb.co/7jWJ8cn

I want to get the main image of wordpress's articles for each article.

**MainActivity class:**

```
list.add( new Model( Model.IMAGE_TYPE, response.body().get(i).getTitle().getRendered(),
                     tempdeatils,
             response.body().get(i).getLinks().getWpFeaturedmedia().get(0).getHref()) );
```

**Model class:**

```
public static final int IMAGE_TYPE =1;
public String title, subtitle, Image;
public int type;

public Model (int mtype, String mtitle, String msubtitle, String image) {
    this.type = mtype;
    this.title = mtitle;
    this.subtitle = msubtitle;
    this.Image = image;
}
```

}

**RetrofitAPI class:**

```
@GET("/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_categories=14&per_pages=10")
Call<List<WPPost>> getPostInfo();
```

**Recyclerview class:**

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final Model object = dataset.get(position);

    ( (ImageTypeViewHolder) holder).title.setText( object.title );
    ( (ImageTypeViewHolder) holder).subtitle.setText( object.subtitle );

    Log.e("Title_", object.title);
    Log.e("Subtitle_", object.subtitle);
    Log.e("Image_", object.Image);

    Glide.with(this.mContext).load(object.Image).into(( (ImageTypeViewHolder) holder).imageView);

    ( (ImageTypeViewHolder) holder).title.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, WPPostDetails.class);
            intent.putExtra("itemPosition", position);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    ( (ImageTypeViewHolder) holder).subtitle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, WPPostDetails.class);
            intent.putExtra("itemPosition", position);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    ( (ImageTypeViewHolder) holder).imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, WPPostDetails.class);
            intent.putExtra("itemPosition", position);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

When I run the App, I get title and part of article but I can't parse the main image of the articles.

Some suggestion?

Comment: No suggestions?

Comment: Did you try manually looking at the stuff that comes back from your API call to see if it matches what the code is expecting? Getting the stuff from Wordpress API is a Wordpress question, but parsing it is a problem in your code, and as that's java you'd beed to ask in e.g. stackoverflow

Comment: Hi @mozboz thank you for your answer. I am trying to get out the correct results from API but I can't solve the exact path. Are you able to help me and give me some suggestion? Maybe, can I provide the API response?